# How do I fix 'command not found' that popped out when I tried 'egrep' from a variable?

Tags: sh

I wanted to make a program that searches all the lines that contains all the factors given, from a file `mydata`. I tried to `egrep` first factor from `mydata` and save it in a variable `a`. Then, I tried to `egrep` the next factor from `a` and save the result to `a` again until I `egrep` all the factors. But when I executed the program, it said

> "command not found" in line 14.

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo -e  "Usage: phoneA searchfor [...searchfor]\n(You didn't tell me what you want to search for.)"

else
    a=""

    for i in $*
    do
    if [ -z "$a" ]
    then
            a=$(egrep "$i" mydata)
    else
            a=$("$a" | egrep "$i")
    fi
    done

    awk -f display.awk "$a"
fi
```

I expected all the lines including all the factors outputted on the screen in the pattern that I made in `display.awk`.

Answer (score 0):

`$a` contains data, not a command. You need to write that data to the pipe.

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    printf '%s\n' "Usage: phoneA searchfor [...searchfor]" "(You didn't tell me what you want to search for.)" >&2
    exit 1
fi

a=""

for i in "$@"; do
  if [ -z "$a" ]; then
    a=$(egrep "$i" mydata)
  else
    a=$(printf '%s' "$a" | egrep "$i")
  fi
done

awk -f display.awk "$a"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I modified my code and was able to get rid of the command not found error.
But then I bumped into a new problem. The program does not print what it should. I will ask in a new question about this.